# How to make on left click of a button add 1 to a value in a object, and a right click to subtract 1

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to html and i'm having troubles with using scripts in html. i learned javascript on the csp code.org course and right now i'm teaching myself html. I'm ok with javascript but i'm not really sure what tags and html specific javascript commands to use when trying to combine the two languages.

so tldr 3 things

so i want the p1 element text next to the button to say the value of bikeHorn.amount

and when i left click the button, i want to increase bikeHorn.amount by one

and when i right click the button, i want to decrease bikeHorn.amount by one

thank you!

```js
var bikeHorn = {
    amount: 0,
    type: "sound",
    level: 1,
    exp: 0,
    damage: 4,
    prestige: false,
    propAccuracy: 95,
};
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
      <img src="images/bike.png" alt="bike" width="64" height="64">    
      <p1>1</p1>            
  </button>
</div>
```

extra info, bikeHorn.amount is an integer that goes up or down by one

Comment: You have a single JS object in your example. No event handlers or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code snippet below for implementation in javascript without jquery.
We have created a span with id **amount** and displaying the value of bikeHorn.amount in it. Also, we have added event listeners to handle left and right click on the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<div>
  <button id="horn">
    <img src="images/bike.png" alt="bike" width="64" height="64" />
    <span id="amount">1</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script>
  var bikeHorn = {
    amount: 0,
    type: "sound",
    level: 1,
    exp: 0,
    damage: 4,
    prestige: false,
    propAccuracy: 95,
  };
  var el = document.getElementById("horn");
  var displayEl = document.getElementById("amount");
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    bikeHorn.amount += 1;
    displayEl.innerHTML = bikeHorn.amount;
  });
  el.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    bikeHorn.amount -= 1;
    displayEl.innerHTML = bikeHorn.amount;
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add the correct events to the button inside the javascript. `click` will handle the left button and `contextmenu` will handle the right click.

```js
var bikeHorn = {
  amount: 0,
  type: "sound",
  level: 1,
  exp: 0,
  damage: 4,
  prestige: false,
  propAccuracy: 95,
};
//  Select the button from the page.
var button = document.querySelector( 'button' );
//  Select the paragraph tag.
var paragraph = button.querySelector( 'p' );
//  Add a click event to the button for the left-click.
button.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
  bikeHorn.amount += 1;
  paragraph.innerHTML = bikeHorn.amount;
});
//  Add a contextmenu event to the button for the right-click.
button.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', function( event ) {
  // Prevent the default behaviour so the contextmenu won't show.
  event.preventDefault();
  bikeHorn.amount -= 1;
  paragraph.innerHTML = bikeHorn.amount;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
    <img src="images/bike.png" alt="bike" width="64" height="64">
    <p>0</p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the initial value inside the button has to match the value inside bikeHorn. So if bikeHorn amount starts at 0, so should the HTML inside the paragraph, else you won't see a change on the first left click.

Comment: Update button text too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can use below code for click on button and replace $("p").html(); with your code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){         
   $('#box').mousedown(function(event) {  
    switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
     $("p").html("Left Mouse Clicked");
     break;
    case 2:
     $("p").html("Middle Mouse Clicked");
     break;
    case 3:
     $("p").html("Right Mouse Clicked");
     break;
    default:
     $("p").html("Option Not Found..");
    }
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="box">Button</button>
<p></p>
```

Hope it help you.
Do accept it as answer if it solve your issue as other can refer it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be helpfully for someone.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var bikeHorn = {
      amount: 0,
      type: "sound",
      level: 1,
      exp: 0,
      damage: 4,
      prestige: false,
      propAccuracy: 95,
    };

    function DoWork(event) {
      if (event.button == 0) //left click
      {
        bikeHorn['amount'] = bikeHorn['amount'] + 1;
        document.getElementById('bikeHornAmount').innerHTML = bikeHorn['amount'];
      } else if (event.button == 2) //rigth click
      {
        bikeHorn['amount'] = bikeHorn['amount'] - 1;
        document.getElementById('bikeHornAmount').innerHTML = bikeHorn['amount'];
      }
    }
  </script>

  <div>
    <button oncontextmenu="return false;" onmousedown="DoWork(event)" style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="avatar.png" alt="bike" width="64" height="64">
  </button>
    <p id="bikeHornAmount" style="display:inline-block;">0</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

With oncontextmenu="return false;" into the button I just avoid to show contextMenu on right click. The 'DoWork' function is taking the mouse down event and depending of event.button value you can identify what kind of click was done. Using document.getElementById function  you can locate the paragraph object and with the innerHtml you can change the value wrapped for the paragraph. You should see that there are a little difference with the others solution like this works with only do the mouse down event. I hope you can go on!